# cppcms url mapping in template files

Tags: routes, cppcms

When I add this rout to my server

```
server::server(cppcms::service &srv) : cppcms::aplication(srv)
{
    dispacher().assign("/(\\d+)/get/(\\w+)", &server::get, this, 1, 2);
}
```

1. How can I assign this rout with `mapper().assign()` to be able to use routs as `server/1/get/hello` or `server/2/get/hello`?
2. How can I use this rout in template file with url?

`<% url "1/get" using [a variable] %>` does work?

Answer (score 0):

First of all take a look on: http://cppcms.com/wikipp/en/page/cppcms_1x_tut_url_mapping

What you are missing is mapper:

```
mapper().assign("get","/{1}/get/{2}");
```

And than

```
<% url "get" using [a variable for number], [a variable for text] %>
```